# how to set cookie for cloudfront url from django

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cookies, amazon-cloudfront

In [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-setting-signed-cookie-custom-policy.html) it says, you can set cookie to their domain like this:

```
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Policy=eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQiOlt7IlJlc291cmNlIjoiaHR0cDovL2QxMTExMTFhYmNkZWY4LmNsb3VkZnJvbnQubmV0L2dhbWVfZG93bmxvYWQuemlwIiwiQ29uZGl0aW9uIjp7IklwQWRkcmVzcyI6eyJBV1M6U291cmNlSXAiOiIxOTIuMC4yLjAvMjQifSwiRGF0ZUxlc3NUaGFuIjp7IkFXUzpFcG9jaFRpbWUiOjE0MjY1MDAwMDB9fX1dfQ__; Domain=d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Signature=dtKhpJ3aUYxqDIwepczPiDb9NXQ_; Domain=d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: CloudFront-Key-Pair-Id=K2JCJMDEHXQW5F; Domain=d111111abcdef8.cloudfront.net; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly
```

but my django code:

```
response.set_cookie(
   'CloudFront-Policy',
   'eyJTdGF0ZW1lbnQ...',
    domain=settings.AWS_CLOUDFRONT_DOMAIN,
    secure=True,
    httponly=True
)
```

not setting the cookie to their domain. I know it is security issue, but why AWS mentions this in documentation? any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

okay, at the end, the solution was to use cname with altername domain. :/ turned out to be the right way anyway.